Playwright is Slow to Start Tests: Long Delay Before Execution Begins
I'm experiencing significant delays when running Playwright typescript UI front-end automation tests. This happens even when I run the Playwright test examples that come with the initial installation.
Specifically, after executing the command npx playwright test --ui, running tests through the playwright test runner from the playwright extension, or after executing npx playwright test --ui. It takes about 10 to 15 seconds before the Playwright UI appears and the tests start executing.
It seemed like even running the npx playwright --version command had a significant delay
OS: Windows 11
Node.js Version: 22.5.1
Playwright Version: 1.47.2
When I watch video tutorials of other people running the tests, they start kicking off almost instantly without a delay. Does anyone have suggestions on what else I can check or try to resolve this issue? Video of the test execution with the delay
I have tried running the Playwright tests in all of the different ways but there is always a delay before they start executing.

Please share a complete, minimal runnable , reproducible code example so that others can reproduce the exact issue and suggest something effectively.

See this - https://search.app?link=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fminimal-reproducible-example&utm_campaign=aga&utm_source=agsadl2%2Csh%2Fx%2Fgs%2Fm2%2F4
